# Does AWS charge for CPU Usage?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I am considering getting `t3.medium` Type EC2 run Web Server (Apache, PHP, MySQL) and it also make a lot of use of data processing (PHP script running in the background making a lot of use between MySQL and API connection)

If a CPU usage spike to 90%-100% for 3 hours no-stop - will I get charged extra for CPU Usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS gives you control over this. Typically the T instance have a hard limit on the CPU allowed, with no additional costs. The new [T2 / T3 unlimited capability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html) lets you use more CPU and get charged for it. It's probably still going to be cheaper than dedicated CPU instances like the M series.

In short, if use your available CPU credits then yes you will get charged for CPU use.

Comment: Is there a way to run a benchmark on existing local server vm (Vmware ESXi) and I would know what type of instance spec I need on AWS?

Comment: I don't know anything about VMware sorry, but I haven't heard of anything. I think people typically take their best guess at the AWS instance type / size required based on CPU / RAM and then monitor with CloudWatch. Starting with the T3 series is probably a good approach, you can easily change instance types later. I suspect most servers are over-provisioned - for example I have a t2.nano running five low volume Wordpress production websites, which includes Nginx, PHP, MySQL, and a few additional tools.

Comment: @user88432 you could measure your average cpu load and look at this table under Product Details https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/ if your average CPU is below the percentage specified, you should be OK with the appropriate t3 instance. This assumes your cpu usage is reasonably spiky, ie. At least 60% of the time if is near 0. You should be able to run it without unlimited then. Otherwise it will be an exercise of test and measure to see if t3 unlimited or c5 is cheaper.

Comment: Measure average cpu load for past 24 hours?

Comment: AWS charges you running time per hour - if you run your server even for 10 seconds you will be charged for a full hour. So run benchmarks for around 50 minutes then shut down your server. It will cost you less than 10 cents on average. (note that if you keep booting and shutting down you can easily pay for several hours usage within the span of 1 minute)

Comment: @slebetman AWS [charges by the second](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/) for EC2 and EBS, as of Sept 2017.